# Mutual fund capital gain on my 1099-DIV : no cost basis?

Tags: united-states, taxes, stocks, mutual-funds

I am in the USA. I have some mutual fund shares that I bought directly from a mutual fund company many years ago spread out over 20+ purchases at different prices.

Last year the fund apparently gave out a capital gain distribution that was reinvested. I can see that in the 1099-DIV form that was sent to me, box 2a ("Total capital gain dist") shows something like $1000.

Now, I am used to seeing more information that my online brokerage provides me on a 1099-B / 8949 showing every stock sale and its cost basis. I would then calculate the net gain or loss accordingly.

How do I treat this capital gain distribution? Is the $1000 treated as a net gain? I called the mutual fund company, and they said there's no cost basis associated with it.

Comment: A capital-gains distribution is **already net**: it is the amounts the fund received for selling securities minus *their* basis in each such sale (and minus any available carryforward from a prior year), divided evenly over all the shares of the fund. Because you had the distribution reinvested, *your* basis in *your* holding in the fund is increased by that amount, and in the future when you sell (unless you die first) your gain will be that much lower.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085: Yes, that's what I figured. It was then a question of whether box 2a is "long-term" or "short-term" capital gain. In the absence of that information, I needed cost basis and purchase date to get the net gain.

Comment: I don't get that logic -- both short- and long-term items can have basis. But **2a is only long-term**. The instructions on the back (perhaps a separate page if using a substitute form) and also the "Where to Report" table in the 1040 instructions tell you to put 2a on Schedule D line 13, which is in Part II Long-Term. Note you don't put it on 8949 so it doesn't need dates, or basis. If a fund makes short-term gain distributions they are just included in 1a (and not included in 1b) so they add to ordinary income on 1040 line 9a.

Answer (score 3):

The capital gain is either short-term or long-term and will be indicated on the 1099-DiV. You pay taxes on this amount as the capital gain was received in a taxable account (assuming since you received a 1099-DIV). More info here:
https://www.mutualfundstore.com/brokerage-account/capital-gains-distributions-taxable

Comment: The problem is that I don't know if the "Total capital gain dist" value in 1099-DIV box 2A is long-term or short-term.