# What is the relation and difference between capital gain distribution and capital gain?

Tags: united-states, taxes, investing, capital-gain, capital-gains-tax

In US federal tax, 
what is the relation and difference between capital gain distribution and capital gain?

For example, the two terms are distinct in the instructions of 1040

> Exception  1.  You  do  not  have  to  file  Form 8949 or Schedule D
>   if both of the  following apply.
>
> 1. You  have  no  capital  losses,  and  your  only  **capital  gains**  are  **capital  gain  distributions**  from  Form(s)  1099-DIV,  box 2a
>      (or substitute statements).
> 2. None  of  the  Form(s)  1099-DIV  (or  substitute  statements)  have  an  amount in box 2b (unrecaptured section  1250 gain), box 2c
>      (section 1202 gain),  or box 2d (collectibles (28%) gain).

Thanks.

Comment: Similar: http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/62784/mutual-fund-capital-gain-on-my-1099-div-no-cost-basis

Answer (score 7):

Capital gains are when you sell an asset for more than it was purchased for. This can occur when you sell a house, collectible, stocks, bonds.

A capital gain distribution is when the mutual fund, or ETF, has sold assets and now has capital gains. They then pass the gains onto the investors. These gains are either paid directly to the investors, or are used to purchase additional shares and those are credited to the investors accounts.

If you sell an asset you need to include additional information to be able to determine the capital gain, and thus the taxes.

If you are receiving a distribution of capital gains, the math and documentation was already done by the trustee. Of course when you sell shares, or withdraw funds then you will have to provide the numbers to determine if those shares have gains.

The actual taxes if any depend on the type of account: Taxable, IRA, 401K, Roth or not.

Comment: Thanks. Does capital gain distribution not necessarily mean there is capital gain and can be capital loss? If I remember correctly,  I remember a mutual fund made capital gain distribution in spite of losing money.

Comment: @Tim: if the fund has net capital loss, it is not distributed, but they can carry it forward and subtract it from gains in a future year (with some limitations); you can see this in their annual financial report. Note that a gain or loss (realized or not) on _your shares in the fund_ is completely separate from any gain or loss realized _by the fund on its holdings_. As an extreme example, in 2008 many funds were forced to liquidate holdings when lots of investors panicked and pulled out, so they sometimes realized gains -- and distributed them -- even though their NAV was down about 50%.

Comment: From the [IRS's Reporting Capital Gains page](https://www.irs.gov/uac/reporting-capital-gains): "Capital gain distributions from mutual funds are reported to you on Form 1099-DIV, Dividends and Distributions.  Capital gain distributions are taxed as long-term capital gains regardless of how long you have owned the shares in the mutual funds."